# How to display multiple select statements into one table?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to merge all of these select statements and have the output display 5 different columns with the specified column names. I tried UNION but that is merging the values into one column. Also, I am using the round function to limit the number of decimal places for the average. Is there a better way to do this besides the round function? I am new to SQL.

```
(select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) as "($)Fire Department Average Pay"
from sf_fire sf)

(select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) as "($)Medicine Department Average Pay"
from sf_medicine sm)

select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) as "($)Police Department Average Pay"
from sfs_police sp 

select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) as "($)Not dep Department Average Pay"
from sfs_notdep sn 

select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) as "($)Other Department Average Pay"
from sfs_other so
```

Comment: See [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a single row, you can do them as sub-selects.

```
select
  (select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) from sf_fire) as '($)Fire Department Average Pay',
  (select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) from sf_medicine) as '($)Medicine Department Average Pay',
  (select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) from sfs_police) as '($)Police Department Average Pay',
  (select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) from sfs_notdep)  as '($)Not dep Department Average Pay',
  (select round(avg("TotalPay")::int,2) from sfs_other) as '($)Other Department Average Pay';
```

Note that the column aliases go outside the sub-queries, and there's no need for table aliases.

Note: this suggests a single table might be better instead of multiple tables.